# Are there any security risks attached to letting users add to their own nginx virtual host files?

Tags: security, nginx, configuration-files, user-input, virtualhost

Let's say that I'm giving some people hosting accounts via nginx. If I were to put a line in their virtual host configuration files that includes an extra config file residing in their home directories, could this lead to any sort of security breach?

Here is a user's virtual host file:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name user.example.com;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/user.access.log;
    location / {
        root /home/user/htdocs;
        index index.html index.htm index.php;
    }
    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php-fastcgi/php-fastcgi.socket;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME  /home/user/htdocs$fastcgi_script_name;
        include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
    }

    # The important bit
    include /home/user/extra_config;

}
```

Theoretically, this would be combined with a cron job that checks the timestamp of each extra_config, and reloads nginx if necessary. Ideally users would utilize this to deny access to private files/directories or create rewrites - basically, it would be an alternative to .htaccess. But are there any pitfalls to this approach? Is there a better way to accomplish it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's best to only allow whitelisted config directives.  You don't want a malicious user ("Eve") to highjack another user's traffic.  e.g., I believe a user could construct a config like the following:

```
} 
server {
   listen 80;
   server_name alice.example.com;
   root /home/eve/htdocs;
}
server {
   listen 80;
   server_name bob.example.com;
   root /home/eve/htdocs;
}
server {
   listen 80;
   server_name passwd.example.com;
   root /etc/passwd;
```

Instead, in an ideal world you would take input via some sort of purpose-built UI, and build the appropriate nginx config yourself from that user input.  For example, I allow users to specify IP bans in a similar way -- I have a UI that accepts only a list of IPs.  I then verify the format of the IPs via a regex, and write out nginx deny directives.

Comment: So the "include" statement practically injects the file right into the configuration, extraneous curly braces and all? That's reason enough for me to use a custom parser. Thanks for the help.

Comment: I suppose another thing you'd have to be on the lookout for is bad syntax, even assuming there were no security issues.  nginx won't start up if there are fatal sytax errors in included config files.

Comment: I'm writing a parser that checks for bad syntax as well. At worst, the reload command will fail and simply leave the server as it was.

Comment: One approach you might take, re: syntax: backup the old file, install the new file, and run `nginx -t` to test the config.  If nginx -t fails, reject the new file.